# Formatting long datetime string to remove T character

Tags: c#, regex, xml

I have a number of XML nodes which output a datetime object as string.

The problem is that when outputting both the time stamp and the date they are bonded together with a T Character.

Here is an example

> 2016-01-13T23:59:59

Of course all of the nodes in the XML are of a different type so grouping by name or type is out of the question. Im thinking my only option is to match a pattern with regex and resolve the problem that way.

Below is an example of how the XML would work, you can see that each element is named as something different but they all follow a similar pattern, where the T between the date and the time must be removed and a space replaced instead.

```
<dates>
    <1stDate> 2016-01-13T23:59:59 </1stdate>
    <2ndDate> 2017-01-13T23:55:57 </2ndDate>
    <3rdDate> 2018-01-13T23:22:19 </3rdDate>
</dates>
```

Ideal solution to output like this

```
2016-01-13 23:59:59 
2017-01-13 23:55:57 
2018-01-13 23:22:19
```

I havent had to use Regex before but i know what it is. I have been trying to decode what this cheat sheet means http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1 but to no avail.

**UPDATE**

```
//How each node is output
foreach (XText node in nodes)
{
    node.Value = node.Value.Replace("T"," "); // Where a date occurs, replace T with space. 
}
```

The `<date>` elements provided in the example may contain dates in my XML but may not include the word date as a name.

e.g.

```
<Start>  2017-01-13T23:55:57  </start>
<End>    2018-01-13T23:22:19  </End>
<FirstDate> 2018-01-13T23:22:19 </FirstDate>
```

The main reason I would have liked a regex solution was because I need to match the date string with a pattern that can determine if its a date or not, then i can apply formatting.

Comment: how about just replacing `T`? `.Replace("T"," ")`

Comment: @Selman22 But wait, how does the program know to do this only for datetimes? What happens if I have other strings there with T in them? like a company name for example - "A-TA" or something similar. Updating my answer to show you how it gets outputted.

Comment: You have not provided any information about how you create the XML with the wrong format. That makes it hard to provide good answers to your question.

Comment: *Why* is having the T a problem? That's a standard (ISO-8601) date/time format. What are you using that requires the space?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to convert XML-valid/ISO-standard dates into XML-invalid/non-ISO-standard dates...

Comment: @JonSkeet The XML is being generated as HTML using xslt to provide UI to an end user.

Comment: Then you could make the change in the xslt, surely.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thats a possibility I was not aware I could do that as I have limited knowledge of XSLT. Perhaps I should include an xslt tag in the question?

Comment: I think it would be a bit unfocused then. Maybe try it for yourself in XSLT first, and ask a *separate* XSLT-only question if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not parse that (perfectly valid ISO-8601) date time into a `DateTime`, and then use the built in string formatting to produce a presentable human readable date time?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.Value))
{
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(node.Value.Trim(),
        @"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, 
        out date)
    {
        node.Value = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: should be `HH` not `hh` - OP using 24-hour clock

Comment: If TryParseExact is used it would assure that no other dates are reformatted.

Comment: Quite right on both counts, I've edited to include those - thanks.

Comment: TryParseExact needs a bit more info. i.e. TryParseExact(node.Value, new string[]{"yyyy-MMM-ddTHH:mm:ss,new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None, out date)

Comment: Accidentally posted it early! Should all be included now.

Comment: I've changed the DateTime.TryParseExact format from "s" (ISO 6801) to @"yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm:ss" - that should mean it only matches those exact format dates now as requested.

Comment: It may be valid if you can deduce whether or not it is a datetime by comparing the string. In this case I have to compare the string first.

Comment: The if TryParseExact statement will only pass if it is a date time of that exact format, so this will provide for that. I'll update the answer to remove the "if inside dates node" part based on your update.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(yourString))
{
     yourString.Replace("T", " ");
}
```

**EDIT**

If you would only like to replace the first instance of the letter "T" like I think you are suggesting in your **UPDATE**. You could use this extension method:

```
public static string ReplaceFirst(this string text, string search, string replace)
{
   int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
   if (pos < 0)
   {
      return text;
   }
   return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
 }
```

and you would use it like:

```
yourString.ReplaceFirst("T", " ");
```

Comment: Sorry the question has been updated. The comment left in there was from a previous line in my code that was mistakenly left in and only just corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to do this with regex, the following expression should do the trick:

```
# Positive lookbehind for date part which consists of numbers and dashes
(?<=[0-9-]+)
# Match the T in between
T
# Positive lookahead for time part which consists of numbers and colons
(?=[0-9:]+)
```

**EDIT**

The regex above will **NOT** check if the string is in date/time format. It is a generic pattern. To impose the format for your strings use this pattern:

```
# Positive lookbehind for date part
(?<=\d{4}(-\d{2}){2})
# Match the T
T
# Positive lookahead for time part
(?=\d{2}(:\d{2}){2})
```

Again, this will match the exactly the strings you have but it you should **not** use it to validate date/time values because it will match invalid dates like `2015-15-10T24:12:10`; to validate date/time values use `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTime.TryParse()` methods.

Comment: So this expression will check if the string is in datetime format?

Comment: @KyleT, please see the edit regarding your question.